# QGIS Web View doesn't show up picture correctly

Tags: qgis, image, web, url, sql-view

As a part of my graduation project, im working in data system that can show up features about a railway inspection.
One of the features are images that show up failures. These images are from URL obtained from epicollect.
Sometimes the images are correctly showed up but mostly of the time they are "damaged".

[image]

Any idea of how to fix this?

I want to use web view because there are a lot of images and download them would  a lot of time cause the inspections are periodically!

I already try map tips but it load tooooo slowly!